# How does HTTP POST method transfer data ?

Tags: java, http, stream

I know what is the HTTP header and how the HTTP data format , I also know how to make a HTTP post from Java ,

like

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
try {
    URL realUrl = new URL("http://somesite/somepage.htm");
    URLConnection conn = realUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "*/*");
    conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("user-agent",
           "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1;SV1)");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    out.print(param);
    out.flush();
    in = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
         result.append(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can use some code like this write stream to web server , and read stream also .

Here is my question .

What is the HTTP POST method really do , I mean how does the client communicate to web server ?

What will happen if the web server only read the HTTP POST header and don't read the stream from client ?
Does the stream will stuck in somewhere ?

Thanks .

Comment: >What is the HTTP POST method really do , I mean how does the client communicate to web server ?
Everything you write into `out` will be included in the messages body.
> What will happen if the web server only read the HTTP POST header and don't read the stream from client ? Does the stream will stuck in somewhere ?
No, the message will be created *out of* `out` and the stream should be closable afterwards.

Comment: @Smutje Thank you for your reply , Does the client send all thing at the start  ? your mean , when I received the HTTP POST header , I received the POST data at same time ? Or client will send the header first and send the big body .

Comment: I guess everything at once, as you can send POST data via `curl` from the command line.

Comment: Body content is sent with HTTP headers.The format is headers then a blank line after that message body.